# strange behavior of reverse loop in c# and c++

Tags: c#, c++, loops, for-loop

I just programmed a simple reverse loop like this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 50; i >= 0; i--)
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
```

but it doesn't stop at 0 as expected but goes down far to the negative values, why?
See this ideone sample: http://ideone.com/kkixx8

(I tested it in c# and c++)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You declared the int as unsigned.  It will always be >= 0.  The only reason you see negative values is that your printf call interprets it as signed (%d) instead of unsigned (%ud).

Comment: but printf outputs a negative value

Comment: @MalteSchmitz Not in c#

Answer (score 3):

Although you did not ask for a solution, here are two common ways of fixing the problem:

```
// 1. The goes-to operator
for (unsigned int i = 51; i --> 0; )
    printf("i = %d\n", i);

// 2. Waiting for overflow
for (unsigned int i = 50; i <= 50; i--)
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
```

Comment: nice soultions :) they seem a bit like evil hacks

Comment: For readability I suggest changing `i --> 0` to `i-- > 0`. It's a bit like writing `a------b`, which works but it's intend is not clear (`(a--) - (- (--b))`).

Comment: @Caramiriel `a------b` is actually parsed as `(((a--)--)--)b` which makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

An *unsigned* int can never become negative.

Comment: but printf outputs a negative value

Comment: @MalteSchmitz That's because you're using %d which is for integers, %u is for unsigned intergers.

Answer (score 2):

In C# this code

```
for (uint i = 50; i >= 0; i--)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Produces following output:

```
50
...
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
4294967295
4294967294
4294967293
...
```

You are using an `unsigned int`. It can never be < 0. It just wraps around. You are seeing negative values because of the way you are formatting your output (interpreting it as a signed int).

Answer (score 2):

Loop breaks when `i` would be less than zero. But `i` is unsigned, and it never be less than zero.

Comment: printf converts i from unsigned int to int, and displays signed

Comment: printf supplied with %d thatswhy it printed signed integers

Answer (score 0):

in your for loop

for (unsigned int i = 50; i >= 0; i--)
    printf("i = %d\n", i);

the value of `i` decresed by 1 and when your value of `i==0` then loop decrement try to assign 
`i--` means `i=-1`

The -1 to the right of your equals sign is set up as a signed integer (probably 32 bits in size) and will have the hexadecimal value 0xFFFFFFF4. The compiler generates code to move this signed integer into your unsigned integer `i` which is also a 32 bit entity. The compiler assumes you only have a positive value to the right of the equals sign so it simply moves all 32 bits into `i`. `i` now has the value 0xFFFFFFF4 which is 4294967284 if interpreted as a positive number. But the printf format of %d says the 32 bits are to be interpreted as a signed integer so you get -1. If you had used %u it would have printed as 4294967284.